# Objective c int to double calculation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, double, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/c-programming-division)

I'm trying to calculate the period of accelerometer updates using a user entered frequency.

this is my code:

```
double interval = 1/Freq;
```

interval = period

Freq is an int set by the user.

The problem I'm having is lets say I set Freq to 2Hz so the interval should be 0.5 but instead interval is 0.0000000 why is this? Can I do anything to change it without changing Freq to a double?

Comment: why not declare a temporary double which you use for the calculation, leaving `Freq` an int, doing `1.0/tmpFreq` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using integer division: (both `1` and `Freq` are integers). So the result will be an integer, and more exactly `0` in this case.

You can do something like this:

```
double interval = 1.0 / Freq;
```

Or

```
double interval = 1 / (double)Freq;
```

Answer (score 0):

do it this way,

```
double interval = 1.0/Freq;
```