# Integer division always zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio, math, floating-point, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/c-programming-division)

probably my question is very simple and stupid.
I would like to store the value of a division, in particular `1 / x` where `x` is a
integer value.

```
int x = 17;
double result = 1/x;
```

I try to do it but I always get `0.000000 ...` I try to enter a value fixed in x, for example `1/17` but always get the same value .. what's Wrong?

Comment: [C++. Dividing 1 by any number gives 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13163964/995714)

Comment: 1/17 is always 0...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are doing integer division.

Try the following and it will work as expected:

```
int x = 17;
double result = 1.0 / x;
```

The type of the `1` in the expression you have above is `int`, and the type of `x` is int. When you do `int / int`, you get an int back. You need at least one of the types involved to be floating point (`float` or `double`) in order for floating point division to occur.

Unlike in Mathematics, division in C++ can either refer to truncated integer division (what you did) or floating point division (what I did in my example). Be careful of this!

In my example, explicitly what we have is `double / int -> double`.

Comment: Or to make it clear: `double result = (double)1 / x;`

Comment: @Nobody So you mean `double result = 1.0 / x;`? Well, the compiler will do this for you but he might laugh at you for not recognising a double literal yourself.

Comment: @Christian Rau It was more of a didactic example to make the automatic type more visible. Of course as a programmer I would always write `1.0` because it is much shorter.

Comment: With POD types all mathematical operations are done on parameters of the **same type**. The result type is the same as the input parameters. If the input parameters do not have a matching type then one parameter will be promoted to the type of the other.