# jeo=(1/(1+decade)); not giving me accurate answer

Tags: c, floating-point

```
int decade;
float jeo;
PRINT("Enter Decade point =\r\n");
scanf("%d",&decade);
print_decimal(decade);
PRINT("\r\n");
jeo=(1/(1+decade));
PRINT("Decade point =");
print_decimal(jeo);//my function for showing floating point number.
PRINT("\r\n");
```

I have wrote this code in IAR embedded workbench software for ARM controller, but it's not giving me accurate answer, can anyone tell me why??
"when i am entering 3. it's giving me 0 answer".

Comment: Integer division is the immediate issue. You also have a pole for decade being -1 which is undefined behaviour, although IEEE754 does define it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Division result is always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345902/division-result-is-always-zero)

Comment: there are tons of duplicates [Dividing 1/n always returns 0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13331054/995714), [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9455271/995714), [C++. Dividing 1 by any number gives 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13163964/995714)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just doing your calculation with `integer` and assign afterwards to a `float` value. This will remove the digits after the decimal point.

Try this:

```
jeo=(1.0/(1.0+decade));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the result of an [integer division](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Division) to `jeo`. In this case, if `decade` is any integer other than 0, the result of integer division will be 0. (Note: If `decade` is `-1`, you will have undefined behavior as a result of division by `0`)

> When the type after usual arithmetic conversions is an integer type, the result is the algebraic quotient (not a fraction), rounded in implementation-defined direction (until C99)truncated towards zero (since C99)

So make either the numerator or the denominator a `float`.

```
jeo=((float)1/float(1+decade);
```

Comment: instead of `(float)1` it'll be clearer to use `1.0f`. But in general doubles should be used unless you know you really need a float

Comment: @phuclv: Agree. OP defined `jeo` as float.

Comment: @Ati: You are welcome. Check out this link as to what to do when your question is answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jeo=1/(1+float(decade));
```

this is because when trying to employ an integer in a logical expression like that, the result is calculated **in integer** first then converted to float. This procedure ,of course, removes the digits after the decimal point and adds artificial 0s.