# Problem with int to float typecasting and couting

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, integer

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int nominals[15] = {50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};
    float numer;
    cin>>numer;
    numer = numer * 100;
    int numer2 = (int)numer;
    while(numer2 != 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<15; i++)
        {
            if(numer2 >= nominals[i])
            {
                numer2 = numer2 - nominals[i];
                if(nominals[i] >= 100)
                {
                    cout<<nominals[i] / 100<<" ";
                }
                else
                {
                    float nominal = nominals[i] / 100;
                    cout<<nominal<<" ";
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what I've tried here is separating a given number to values present in the table nominals. With values >= 100 it works properly. However, with values < 100 it doesn't works at all, at least it doesn't cout it. Yet i can't debug it cause gdb doesn't work with it at all.
Note the conversion taking place in the first part of main() function and converting int to float and dividing it by 100 after a value satisfies a certain criteria.
Also, the program doesn't work with a dot, but partially does when a comma is present instead.

So far I've tried rewriting the code altogether, testing it on different platforms, to no avail. I have no idea how to get it to work, that's why I'm here.

And please, don't be too harsh, I'm a novice.

Comment: " cause gdb doesn't work with it at all" what does that mean? Thats the primary issue you need to get fixed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the debug feature won't load

Comment: @whitehat You really need to find out why gdb is not working, but that is a completely separate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++. Dividing 1 by any number gives 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163964/c-dividing-1-by-any-number-gives-0)

Comment: You might have better results if you don't mix integers with floating point numbers.  You do know 100 is an integer, 100.0f is a float and 100.0 is a double right?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I've actually forgotten about the existence of double... lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
float nominal = nominals[i] / 100; // integer division
```

to

```
float nominal = nominals[i] / 100.0; // floating point division
```

Dividing one integer by another always produces another integer (any fractional part of the division is discarded).