# casting integer division into double in C

Tags: c, casting

Why does the code

```
double slope = (double)changeY/changeZ
```

set slope to 0.0, when in the program I have, changeX = 20 and changeY = 10 (both ints)?

Comment: You are using changeY/*changeZ* in the example above instead of *changeX*. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Because you are doing something wrong. However, we cannot tell you exactly what it is, with this little information. Give a minimal, yet complete code example, where we see the declarations and definitions of `changeX` etc. and the calculation of `slope`.

Comment: @Alberto: no - this is not needed - the OP's code with the cast should work as expected. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What is `changeZ`, the value you're dividing by? If that is large enough, the result will be small enough to be displayed as `0.000000` with `printf("%f\n", slope);`.

Comment: Maybe changeZ if close or equal to infinity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9455271/608639)

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you are using the wrong variable. Try this:

```
int changeX = 20;
int changeY = 10;

double slope = (double)changeY/changeX;
```

The cast operator () has higher priority than /. This expression will get evaluated as:

- Cast `changeY` to a `double`.
- Implicitly convert `changeX` to a `double`. If one operand is `double`, then the other operand gets balanced to a `double` as well (this is formally called "the usual arithmetic conversions").
- Divide the two operands. The result will be a double.
- Store this temporary "result-double" into another double called slope.

Comment: +1: not sure why this got an immediate down-vote - it's the closest thing we have to a correct answer so far ?

Comment: Note that *slope* is more likely to be `changeY/changeX`.

Comment: @PaulR Ah yeah, probably. Thanks, I'll edit (even though it isn't related to the particular issue).

Comment: Well if we're going to guess what the problem is we might as well use the best possible guess given the limited data. ;-)

Comment: The answer states the result of division is a double. The result is semantically a double but may actually have more precision.