# what the conversion is applied in the expression (double to int)

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

there is an expression (as a part of median calculation):

```
auto iter1 = std::next(first, floor(size/2) - 1 );
double result  = *iter1 + *(iter1 + 1)) / 2;
```

where the type of the value under iterators is int.

expected result e.g.:

> 1.5 = (1 + 2 ) / 2

however , in case of values 1 and 2 the result is 1, looks like implicit conversion to int

please explain, what the rule (or my misunderstanding?) is applied here

Comment: What's `iter1`? Also, `/ 2.f`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division always zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Comment: The result of `(1 + 2)` already has type `int`, no implicit conversion required.

Comment: I don't see any cast.

Comment: What is the type of `size`? What is the type of `*iter1`?

Comment: Unrelated, I hope you never try this with a sequence of length 1. It won't work (and probably should be fixed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second expression `double result  = *iter1 + *(iter1 + 1)) / 2;`: as per operator precedence, the evaluation of `*(iter1 + 1)) / 2` is done first; and since the operands of the `/` operator are both ints, the sub-expression will result in [integer division](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307993/why-does-integer-division-result-in-an-integer). The result of the integer division is then added to `*iter1`.

> there is an expression (as a part of median calculation):
>
> ```
> double result  = *iter1 + *(iter1 + 1)) / 2;
> ```

Since the common type of the expression in the right hand side is an `int`. No [conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) is done. Having at least one `double` will fix you problem. (Also note the parenthesis I added to fit your example).

```
double result  = (*iter1 + static_cast<double>(*(iter1 + 1))) / 2.0;
```

Comment: I'd cast one of the dereferenced iterators instead, so that you also avoid possible overflow problems in the sum.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, Yeap. Good concern. Fixed.

Comment: I changed it to what I think it should be (parentheses). Please revert if you disagree.

Comment: @anatolyg Given, the OP's example, I agree.

Comment: it looks clear, but I'd like to read about this more, can someone provide me with a description of this rule in terms of c++ standard? thank you