# How to get the square root of a periodic decimal point number using C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I try to get the square root of a periodic decimal number the result is `0`.

Example code:

```
sqrt(4/99)
```

The accuracy not important, it is okay to truncate some digits.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you share some **working** code to demonstrate it?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero

Comment: These questions pop up from time to time. But what source of learning are all those new programmers using? Basic arithmetic and its quirks is usually covered early in a [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: how to get square root of a periodic decimal point? sqrt() method outputs zero

Answer (score 8):

You used an integer as input to the `sqrt()` function.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << std::sqrt(4 / 99) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::sqrt(4.0 / 99) << std::endl;
}

Output
0
0.201008
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works