# Store double in array C++ using Xcode

Tags: c++, arrays, double

I try to save declare a double array in C++ on Xcode.

```
double array[size];
```

But when I print the values,

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    cout<<array[i]<<"  ";
}
```

It's printing integers.

```
void display(int grade[][size_of_qz]) {

    double stAve[size_of_st];
    computeStAve(grade, stAve);

    cout << "Student      Ave         Quizes\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < size_of_st; row++) {
        cout << row + 1 << "        " << stAve[row] << "          ";
        for (int col = 0; col < size_of_qz; col++) {
            cout << grade[row][col] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void computeStAve(int grade[][size_of_qz], double stAve[]) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < size_of_st; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size_of_qz; col++) {
            temp += grade[row][col];
        }
        stAve[row] = temp / size_of_qz;
        temp = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you assign values to the array elements?

Comment: Yep... I already assigned

Comment: Then edit your question with that code.

Comment: Were you expecting the value to be printed *with* decimal points?

Comment: Is the code clear?
yes, I want print with decimal point

Comment: Maybe is there any mistake on passing to functions?

Comment: If you are **not** printing decimals for **any** number, then that would suggest that the value being saved in stAve[x] is wrong. std::cout prints floating point numbers with decimals by default (if its not a whole number). So the printing is not the issue.

Comment: I also suspect `stAve[row] = temp / size_of_qz;` being an integer division.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this line is the cause of your problems:

```
stAve[row]=temp/size_of_qz;
```

It is the same as: double = (int / int). Your division is getting converted to an int. You need to do something like:

```
stAve[row]=(double)temp/size_of_qz;
```

Comment: Really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you are expecting to print a certain number of digits, start your main function with a

```
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
```

and the library to include would be **iomanip**.

Comment: The default C++ precision is 6, changing it to 2 is not going to change the fact that he's seeing integers when expecting floats.

Comment: right, that's my bad. misinterpreted the question. Thanks for the feedback