# Why do these doubles between 0 and 1 anyways print 0?

Tags: c++

For some reason, when I try to print doubles between 0 and 1 out, they always evaluate to 0. For example, these all print 0:

```
double width_ratio = 180 / 360;
double height_ratio = 80 / 100;
std::cout << 180 / 360 << std::endl;
std::cout << width_ratio << std::endl;
std::cout << height_ratio << std::endl;
```

Actual output:

```
0
0
0
```

My expected/desired output:

```
0.5
0.5
0.8
```

How am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: 180 is an int, 360 is an int, int divided by int results in int

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Comment: In `std::cout << 180 / 360 << std::endl;`, dividing an integer by another integer results in an integer.

Comment: Hint: `180.0 / 360.0`

Comment: I got it now. I guess it was a careless mistake on my part. Thanks everyone!