# Why is Visual studio returning only integers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just upgraded my computer and had to reinstall Visual Studio 2019, and I realized for some reason I can't work with float values.
For example if I do a `cout << (3/2);` , it will return `1`.
I've tried looking into the `float.h` file but I don't know what to change.
I guess it's a simple fix, I tried to google it but I didn't find a solution yet

Comment: Because 3 and 2 are both integers. You need to make at least one of them a floating point for the calculation to happen as a floating point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Comment: Adding on to what others have said, this has nothing to do with reinstalling Visual Studio. This is just how integer division works in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You did integer division, so you got an integer back. If you tried `std::cout << (3.0 / 2.0);`, you'd get a `double`.

If you want floats: `std::cout << (3.0f / 2.0f);` gets you there.

How you type your literals matters in C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was working with Visual Studio 2017 before and it was working fine, strange :/

Comment: VS 2017 would have treated the code you posted exactly the same. Something else (that you wrote) changed.