# how to write the correct answer in the divisions C++

Tags: c++, math, division

so the intention of the code is that it generate two random numbers between 1 and 100 for a division and i write the answer, then it tells me if its correct or not. For example 59/89 = 0.66 but says its incorrect (im sorry for the bad english)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int divC = 0; int divI = 0;
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

        char exit = 'n' ;
        int divR1 = rand()%100; int divR2 = rand()%100;
            double reDiv= 0; double solution = divR1 / divR2;
                cout << "---------DIVISION---------" << endl;
                cout << "Operation " << divR1 << " / " << divR2 << endl;
                cout << "Answer: ";
                cin >> reDiv;
                    if (reDiv == solution)
                    {
                        cout << "Correct." << endl;
                        divC + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
                        divI + 1;
                    }
                cout << "EXIT? [Y/N]: ";
                cin >> exit;

    return 0;
}
```

this is what i made, i hope i explain my problem well

Comment: Classic [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9455271/555045)

Comment: Or [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/555045) but I wish there was one for C++ specifically (it works the same, but still)

Comment: Once you fix the integer division problem you'll likely run into [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @RetiredNinja and problem of "almost equal"

Comment: If you only care for 2 digits after the comma and always want to round down, you may want to do `int resultTimes100 = (100* divR1) / divR2; ... if (static_cast<int>(reDiv * 100) ==  resultTimes100)`. Of course division by 0 would be problematic. You definetly should add logic for preventing a division by 0 to your code.

Comment: @harold I guess [Why does dividing two int not yield the right value when assigned to double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571326/995714) can be used

Comment: thanks a lot everyone, the posts are helping me so much

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

- The first is that solution is 0, because an integer division is performed and is only after the computation converted into a double.  You must have at least one `double` term to get a double division:

  ```
   double solution = (double)divR1 / divR2;
  ```
- The second is that even if the division was correct, it would not meet your expectations because `59/89` is not `0.66`, but `0.66292134831460669542`.  So if you want to allow some degree of approximation, e.g. two digits after the comma,  you should do the comparison differently:

  ```
  if (abs(reDiv-solution)<0.01)
  ```

---

In general, [floating point numbers are rarely completely accurate after the decimal](https://medium.com/the-technical-archaeologist/is-cobol-holding-you-hostage-with-math-5498c0eb428b).  So comparing with some degree of precision, yields more reliable results than making a strict comparison.

My favourite example:

```
double r1=.01, r0=0.0; 
for (int i=100; i; i--)               // add 100 times 0.01
    r0 += r1; 
cout << r0<<endl                      // result is 1 (rounded at display)
     <<setprecision(20)<<r0 << endl   // but in reality it is not 1 even if it's not far from it
     <<" problem with test: "<< (r0==1.0) <<endl    // direct comparison fails
     <<" reliable test: "<< ( abs(r0-1.0)<0.01 ) << endl;  // check with a 2 digit precision
```

Comment: ooh ok,, why do i need to put the "(double)"?

Comment: @LeNobody009 `(double)divR1` says that `divR1` is to be converted to `double`.  The compiler then understands that you want to divide a double by an int, and that a double division is required.

Comment: @LeNobody009 otherwise the compiler considers both operands of the `/` expressions of type `int` and `<int> / <int>` results in an `int` value that is truncated; the conversion of `int` to `double` would happen afterwards. The expression in the answer results in one of the operands to be converted to `double` before the division and if one of the operands of `/` is a `double`, the other gets converted to one before the division happens resulting in the division of 2 floating point values.

Comment: @LeNobody009 You're welcome! DOn't hesitate to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;-)