# Why do I get the wrong results while calculating the mean of the array using openMP?

Tags: c, loops, openmp, reduction

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 5

int X[N];

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int moy = 0;

    // Initialize the array (you should populate it as needed)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        X[i] = i * 2; // Example initialization
    }

    // Calculate the average
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:moy)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        moy += X[i] / N;
    }

    // Count elements greater than the average
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:num)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (X[i] > moy) {
            num++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

If I write the print statements for mean, num and elements of the array I get the following output: 
Average (moy): 2 
Elements in X: 0 2 4 6 8  
Number of elements greater than the average: 3

Comment: Probably because of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero

Comment: The "pro tip" would be to get it working without OpenMP first.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an openmp problem , you declared `moy` as an `int` and then to calculate the mean you do:

`moy += X[i] / N;`

your `X` array contains `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` and `N = 5`, when the division is performed you are trying to put a `double` inside an `int` so your sum becomes essentially:

`0/5 = 0` +
`2/5 = 0` +
`4/5 = 0` +
`6/5 = 1` +
`8/5 = 1` = `0+0+0+1+1` = `2`

you need to either make `moy` and `X` a `double` or, better, to make `moy` a `double`, sum all the elements inside `moy` AND THEN do `moy/N` to get the correct result