# Double returns 0

Tags: c++, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/c-programming-division)

I am trying to convert values into the Mel Filter but, every time I output the result, it is always "0" even though it is a double. Should it be a float? Here is an article on the equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale

Here is the functions:

```
double MFCC::mel_filter(int val)
{
     double tmp;
     tmp = 2595 * log10(1 + val / 700);
     cout << tmp << endl;
     return tmp;
    }

    vector<double> MFCC::mel_frame(int size)
    {
    vector<double> mel_Frame;
    for(int i=1; (i < size); i++)
    {
          this->mel_filter(i);
    }

    return mel_Frame;
    }
```

In main, I will pass values such as.. (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ......)

And if "1" was entered then the equation would be:

```
m = 2595 * log10(1 + 1 / 700) = 1.6
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Make your values doubles, not ints. i.e. 2595.0, 1.0, 700.0

Comment: Try `1 + val/700.0` -- `/` is integer division if both operands are integer

Comment: It's worth nothing that, though you declare and return `vector<double> mel_Frame;`, you never actual write any values into it. Your function will always return an empty vector.

Comment: @meagar I am testing, I will write to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is at

```
log10(1 + val / 700)
```

That's using an integer division instead of a real division. Try with

```
log10(1 + val / 700.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of `val` is int. So the expression `val / 700` is evaluated with integer arithmetic. The result is zero.

Answer (score 2):

When you use integer number literals, integer arithmetics are used. That means any decimals will be rounded down. Write the constants explicitly as decimal numbers, and double arithmetics will be used:

```
tmp = 2595.0 * log10(1.0 + val / 700.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
log10(1 + val / (float) 700)
```