# dividing a small number by a larger giving me 0.0

Tags: java, math, double

I am doing a program that calculates radio activity at a previous point in time based on measured radioactivity.

However if the half-life is very large compared with the elapsed time I get a `0.00` as the answer which then leaves me with `A= Ao` at least until `(times[i]-times[0])` gets large.

For example if `(times[i]-times[0]) = 5` and `Thalflife = 6540` I want to get `0.00076452599` however I get `0.0` is double the wrong type to use or is it the `/` command that is giving me the problem?

```
private double[]theoreticalVals(double activity) {
   /* below is an implementation of the activity decay 
    * calculation formula A= Ao/2^(t/Thalflife)
    * An array of values will be returned. 
    * The times array defines the length of the array and gives the point in time values
    */
 double Ao= activity; 
 double [] vals = new double[times.length];
 double a; 
 vals[0]=Ao;                            //initial activity
 for(int i = 1; i<times.length;i++){                
   a =(times[i]-times[0])/Hf;       //  
   double lowerhalfterm = Math.pow(.5,a);                   //  2-(^(t/Thalflife))
   vals[i]= Ao/lowerhalfterm;

}                                          // A=Ao/2^(t/Thalflife)

return vals; 
}
```

Comment: You neither specify a language nor provide the type of `times`, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/c-programming-division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`times` is probably an array of integers, and `Hf` is probably also an integer. You either need to change the declaration of one of those variables to a floating variable, like `double`, or you will need to cast one of the variables in the calculation.

Change the declaration from:

```
int Hf;
```

to:

```
double Hf;
```

Or cast in the calculation:

```
(times[i]-times[0])/((double)Hf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing an int by an int, so you're using integer division. To have double division, one of the operands at least must be a double:

```
double result = ((double) i1) / i2
```