# Can't get program to output the right result in C++

Tags: c++

I was asked to make this program to calculate a persons Body Mass Index. `US_IMPERIAL` is incomplete on account of my noticing `METRIC` not running. I can't figure out the error, as whatever numbers I input, I get 0 as a result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float METRIC (int b, int c)
{
  float res;
  res = b / c / c * 10000;
  return res;
}


float US_IMPERIAL (float d, float e)
{
  float resu;
  resu = (d / e / e) * 703;
  return resu;
}

int main () 
{
  cout << "Hello. BMI CALCULATOR!" << endl <<
    "Press 1 for METRIC or 2 for US imperial: ";
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  if (a == 1) {
    cout << "Enter your weight in KILOGRAMS (KG): ";
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Now enter you height in CENTIMETERS(CM): ";
    int c;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Your BMI is: " << METRIC (b, c);
  } else if (a == 2) {
    // not yet implemented
  } else {
    cout << "Error.";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The amount of white space and the indentation of your code matters for readability. Please format your code in a consistent way to make reading it easier.

Comment: Integer division strikes again. You're storing the result of an *integer division* in a floating point variable. (example of integer div: 3/4 = 0), my guess is you were expecting floating point math.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does division result in zero instead of a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/why-does-division-result-in-zero-instead-of-a-decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `METRIC` function, the expression `b / c / c * 10000` is an *all integer* expression. That will not work very well if you want fractions.

I suggest you turn the arguments `b` and `c` into floating point variables.