# No matter if the condition is true if always executes in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, error-correction

Can someone correct this code please.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    double d;
    double e;
    double f;
    double g;
    f = a / b;
    g = b / a;
    c = 0;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    f = a / b;
    g = b / a;
    if (a == b)
    {
        cout << a << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (f == int(f))
    {
        cout << a << endl;
        return 0;
    }
start:
    while (a * b > c)
        c = c + 1;
    d = c / a;
    e = c / b;
    if (d == int(d))
        if (e == int(e))
        {
            cout << c << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (d != int(d))
            goto start;
        else if (e != int(e))
            goto start;
    if (a * b <= c)
        cout << a * b << endl;
}
```

No matter what the

```
else if(f==int(f))
```

code is always executed. Eg. I put in 3 and 5 and even though 3/5 gives a decimal the else if is always executed and outputs 3. WHAT AM I MISSING HERE?

Comment: Please learn about and apply indentation.

Comment: can you send the corrected if else part please because i am a beginner

Comment: Please try `d = (1.0*c) / a;e = (1.0*c) / b;`. And similar for f and g. If that helps I will explain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Comment: `f = a / b;` at this piont `a` and `b` are uninitialized, leading to undefined behavior. Before doing anything else, fix that.

Comment: first, all the division are integer division, second, what you want to do with `f == int(f)`? create a integer version of f?

Comment: `int/int` truncates its result into another `int`, you need to cast to `float` or `double` before dividing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does division result in zero instead of a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/why-does-division-result-in-zero-instead-of-a-decimal)

Comment: well on my pc if i insert "1" and "2" that else is fired.. maybe you should read about integer division and narrowing conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define type `a` and `b` as **double** not **int**.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and it just works.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

These expression, though they are assigning to double variables, calculate integer divisions.

```
f = a / b;
g = b / a;
d = c / a;
e = c / b;
```

I.e. what gets assigned to the doubles are integer values.

Your if-conditions basically check for integer values and hence always evaluate to true.

In order to avoid the integer division and get actual floating point values assigned to the doubles, you need to make sure early that the compiler interprets them accordingly. E.g.:

```
f = (1.0*a) / b;
g = (1.0*b) / a;
d = (1.0*c) / a;
e = (1.0*c) / b;
```

And, as a comment points out, better always init all your variables (even if here a,b,c would be enough).

```
int a=1;
int b=1;
int c01;
double d=1.0;
double e=1.0;
double f=1.0;
double g=1.0;
```

Comment: @Timo I picked up your advice, hope you take it as a compliment.

Comment: `(1.0*a) / b` instead of `static_cast<double>(a) / b`? Doing an identitiy operation to force a type conversion feels wrong :/ might aswell do `(0.0 + a) / b`

Comment: At least an alternative to potentially risky typecasting or even changing integers to imprecise floating point types.

Comment: Well you can't get any safer than `static_cast`.

Comment: Or `f=a; f/=b;`

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Interesting approach. I think you can make an answer of that, ideally an explained one (and are allowed to do a new one for that, but no guarantees, only my opinion...).

Answer (score 2):

The primary error in your code leading to the problem with the if statement is the integer division. You have to cast the operands to doubles to perform floating point division:

```cpp
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
f = double(a) / double(b);
g = double(b) / double(a);
```

There are other issues to clean up, but this is the one that leads to your question.