# C++ multiply float by fraction

Tags: c++, floating-point, multiplication, fractions

just started C++ from a MATLAB background and getting confused.

```
float farenheit, celcius;
cin >> farenheit;
celcius = (farenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);
cout << "Temperature (c): " << celcius;
```

why does multiplying by 5/9 not work as expected, but this does?:

```
float farenheit, celcius;
cin >> farenheit;
celcius = ((farenheit - 32) * 5) / 9);
cout << "Temperature (c): " << celcius;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/9455271/1741542

Comment: What does `5/9` produce on its own?  Hint: They are both integers.

Comment: Or even better this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/8906722/1741542

Comment: because `int/int` in C++ returns a `int` value, to solve this you can just append a `.0` to one of the 2 numbers `(5 / 9.0);`

Comment: Some big differences with matlab:  integer arithmetic, 0-based arrays.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you use the correct types, like `celcius = (farenheit - 32.f) * (5.f / 9.f);` ?

Comment: `(5 / 9)` -> `(5.0 / 9.0)`

Comment: @＿Static＿assert `(5.f / 9.f);` as I suggested would be quite sufficienct  though. There's no need to bring in `double`s here.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'd argue that OP should switch to using `double` exclusively :)

Comment: @＿Static＿assert  Yes, that's often (nowadays) the wise thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone,

C++ interprets `5` and `9` as `int` values so `5/9` is also an `int`.
5/9 = 0.566 which is truncated down to `0`.

To fix this, append `.0` or `.f` to the values be interpreted as a double or float respectively.

Comment: Was writing an answer myself, but I'm glad you figured it out before I could get it posted. Good work.

Comment: Note: Appending `.0` makes the value into a `double` while `.f` makes it  a `float`. You work with `float`s so, I'd stay with those to not waste CPU.

Comment: Thanks, @TedLyngmo. Amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

C++ considers 5 and 9 to be integers and the division is integer division, which means 5/9 = 0 (it returns the quotient).

So use 5.0 and 9.0 if you want them to be floating points.