# Why it is giving the 0 answer?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double basic = 1000;
double DA = (10/100) * basic;
double HRA = (30/100) * basic;
cout<<"DA = "<<DA<<endl; // why the answer is 0 ?
cout<<"HRA = "<<HRA<<endl; // why the answer is 0 ?
return 0;
}
```

Please Help me....I do not understand why the DA and HRA is giving 0 answer?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error

Comment: 10/100 is 0 -- this is integer math. 10.0/100.0 would be 0.1.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8906722)

Answer (score 1):

10/100 = 0 as 10 and 100 are both int and their result will aslo be int.

Try 10/100.0

30/100.0

Comment: Thank u so much it worked...